# Is there a way to realistically test mobile performance of sites?

Tags: selenium, android-emulator, ios-simulator

What's the best practice for testing the performance of mobile sites in a realistic way?

I'm not interested so much about the collection of the metrics per se, but more about how to drive real devices (iOS, Android) from selenium (or other). Or to use simulators that have similar characteristics (emulating CPU and memory of the targeted devices).

Answer (score 1):

At least for Nokia handsets, you have the Nokia Remote Device Access available. http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/

Not sure if the other manufacturers offer such a service with dev access on real devices on live networks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what your looking for is Selenium's built in AndroidDriver. It does exactly what you want:

> Android WebDriver test can run on emulators or real devices for phone
>   and tablets.

Check out [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver) link for more info

Edit: [Here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver) is the iOS driver

Good Luck!